# heroku login issue

Tags: heroku

I'm running 'heroku login' command and in response I got the following error:

```
Error:       A blocking operation is currently executing. - connect(2) would block (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
Backtrace:   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:48:in `connect_nonblock'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:48:in `rescue in block in connect'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:31:in `block in connect'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:29:in `each'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:29:in `connect'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/socket.rb:16:in `initialize'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:31:in `initialize'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/connection.rb:344:in `new'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/connection.rb:344:in `socket'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/connection.rb:175:in `request_kernel'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.2/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.2.6/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.2.6/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:75:in `api_key'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:184:in `ask_for_credentials'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:216:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:79:in `get_credentials'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:40:in `login'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:22:in `login'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:178:in `run'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:19:in `start'
             C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku login
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.28.7 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2
```

any idea what's wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was happening due to company proxy. From another network everything worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing issues with logging in, try moving your .netrc file. This is where the CLI stores credentials:

> $ mv ~/.netrc ~/.netrc.backup
>
> $ heroku login

On Windows, the file is named _netrc.

Find more on this page:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#troubleshooting